# Oracle 11g install problem on Ubuntu

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, ubuntu

I ran the runInstaller script in the root dir of the extracted zip files. After some pages of the graphical installer it sent me to run

```
/tmp/CVU_11.2.0.1.0_macbook/runfixup.sh
```

as root. It gave me the following errors:

```
# ./runfixup.sh    
Response file being used is :./fixup.response
Enable file being used is :./fixup.enable
Log file location: ./orarun.log
./orarun.sh: 186: [: true: unexpected operator
./orarun.sh: 848: [: unexpected operator
./orarun.sh: 864: [: unexpected operator
./orarun.sh: 882: [: unexpected operator
./orarun.sh: 903: [: true: unexpected operator
./orarun.sh: 1052: [: unexpected operator
./orarun.sh: 1057: [: unexpected operator
./orarun.sh: 1075: [: unexpected operator
./orarun.sh: 1085: [: unexpected operator
./orarun.sh: 1115: [: unexpected operator
./orarun.sh: 1143: [: unexpected operator
./orarun.sh: 1189: [: unexpected operator
./orarun.sh: 139: [: unexpected operator
./orarun.sh: 139: [: unexpected operator
./orarun.sh: 1228: [: unexpected operator
./orarun.sh: 1284: [: unexpected operator
./orarun.sh: 1342: [: unexpected operator
./orarun.sh: 1426: [: unexpected operator
./orarun.sh: 1451: [: unexpected operator
```

What shall I do?

Comment: Wait a second...
"CVU_11.2.0.1.0_macbook" ,.. CVU stands for Cluster Verification Utility....  what installer did you downloaded and from where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) Use an OS that is certified for installing and running Oracle Database (Ubuntu is not amongst them). Native or virtual machine, your choice.

or

b) here is an unofficial guide for installing Oracle 11.2 on Ubuntu Linux
https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1117155

I have never tried myself, but several people succeeded installing Oracle 11.2 on Ubuntu with the help of this.

Comment: I develop a small application with Oracle and I have Ubuntu, that is the story. A page I have found tells that Solaris is recommended, that would be an overkill to install.

Comment: You can also use RHEL which is more friendly for ubuntuers.